# Elasticsearch-Php-Mysql datetime filter and query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, elasticsearch, range

I want to index of my mysql database with elasticsearch. My datas is about datetime. I indexed my datas. I am using PHP 5.5 and Elasticsearch 2.1 and Mysql.

My codes for mapping:

```
$myTypeMapping['properties']['$date']['type']='date';

$myTypeMapping['properties']['$date']['index']='not_analyzed';

$myTypeMapping['properties']['$date']['format']='yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
```

My codes for filter and query: (gte, lte,range query)

```
unset($filter_date);

if(isset($GET['dategte'])){

$filter_date['range']['date']['gte']=(($GET['dategte']));

$filter_date['range']['date']['lte']=(($GET['datelte']));

}

if(is_array($filter_date)){

$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['and'][]=$filter_date;

}
```

My query: (between [2016-01-01 00:00:00]-[2017-12-31 23:59:59])

```
http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?date_gte=2016-01-01 00:00:00&date_lte=2017-12-31 23:59:59
```

-->The fact that needs to find 38 results.

-->But showing only 1 results-> 2017-07-03 14:00:00,

-->Records in 2016, not shown.

If I change the query as follows: (2016-2017)

```
http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?date_gte=2016&date_lte=2017
```

-->38 records coming. That's true. However I would like to query as day month year hours minutes.

Also another query: ([2015-01-01 00:00:00]-[2017-12-31 23:59:59])

```
http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?date_gte=2015-01-01 00:00:00&date_lte=2017-12-31 23:59:59
```

-->38 records coming. It is not correct. Actually, There are 100 registration 2015 between 2017.

I think the problem is about php. But ı am not sure. What is the problem?Please help me.

Comment: You are getting the parameters `$GET['dategte']` and `$GET['datelte']` on PHP but passing `date_gte` and `date_lte` on the URL. Is missing the _

Comment: I know. Actulally $GET['dategte'] is $GET['date_gte '] While I was writig It changed. I made the mistake of writing here

Comment: What's the value of the `$GET['date_gte']` and `$GET['date_let']`?

Comment: I have to date data. `$GET['date_gte']` is minumum date. For example: 2016-01-01 00:00:00. `$GET['date_lte']` is maximum date. For example:2017-01-01 23:59:59 These terms are related to the range query on elasticsearch technology. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)